# Why javascript gives this error?

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

I recently added a function into my code and I'm giving this error:

missing: after property id

Here is the function and everything seems to be correct:

```
function movestt(blk)
{
var blkf=blk;
var blkr=blk;

TweenLite.to('#b'+blk, 0.0, {css:{background-color:'rgba(20,20,150,0.5)'}});

for(var i=0;i<=4;i++)
{

    blkf++;
    blkr--;

    TweenLite.to('#b'+blkf, 0.0, {css:{background- color:'rgba(20,20,150,0.5)'}});

    TweenLite.to('#b'+blkr, 0.0, {css:{background-color:'rgba(20,20,150,0.5)'}});

}

}
```

function run when some button on page is clicked.
I'm using the tweenlite library in other functions so this is not the reason.

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `backgroundColor` instead of `background-color` or `background color`

Valid:

```
backgroundColor
"background-color"
```

invalid properties:

```
background color
background-color
```

Comment: Secnod part was typo and its correct in code (background color). Lemme try first part ;)

Comment: @roberthofer sure take your time. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aw4zb8vz/ undo the changes and hit the JSHINT button - you'll see the errors appear.

Comment: @roberthofer sohuld work. Or it's nothing related to what you asked.

Comment: bro I think the error is something about elements ids. When I delete this function everything is fine.

Comment: @roberthofer brosky, how can I know (from you Q as it currently stands) if you're using your `#b+something` ID correctly?

Comment: Cause im using it in another functions and it works. there is some dives like "b36" "b37" "b38" etc. Im changing id dynamically.